# change data structure of dynamodb data

Tags: python, elasticsearch, amazon-dynamodb

I've to ingest dynamodb data to elastic search. But I'm getting dynamodb data in the format. If I ingest this format to ES I'm unable to query/delete using the keywords in the data.

```
{
"index": {
"_index": "data-index",
"_type": "_doc
"_id": "verBionoVub"
},
"ApproximateCreationDateTime": 1645005038,
"Keys": {
"sk": {
"S": "sk001"
},
"pk": {
"S": "pk001"
}
},
"NewImage": {
"res_type": {
"S": "message"
},
"author": {
"S": "user"
},
"price": {
"N": "15"
},
"product_id": {
"S": "B016JOMAEE"
}}
```

How can I change/get it in this format?

```
{
  "_index": "data-index",
  "_type": "_doc
  "_id": "verBionoVub"
  "author": "user",
  "pk": "pk001",
  "product_id": "B016JOMAEE",
  "res_type": "message",
  "sk": "sk001"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use TypeDeserializer from boto3 for this.

```
from boto3.dynamodb.types import TypeDeserializer, TypeSerializer

def from_dynamodb_to_json(item):
    d = TypeDeserializer()
    return {k: d.deserialize(value=v) for k, v in item.items()}
```

We can also use a third party package dynamodb_json.

```
from dynamodb_json import json_util as djson
data={'some data'}
djson.loads(sample_data)
```

you need to install

```
pip install dynamodb-json
```

for using this package